# When is Runaways set?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, runaways-2017

I always thought *Runaways* was set roughly concurrent with the main MCU films and shows airing around the same time.

However, in *Runaways* S02E08, we see the following line:

> STACY: There really is life out there.
>
> JANET: And we made contact.

Obviously, this would be a peculiar thing to say even circa *Thor*, and would be very strange after the Chitauri invasion of New York in *Avengers*.

When is *Runaways* set in the MCU timeline?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only direct connection between Runaways and any of the movies of the MCU is the appearance of the character Tina Minoru in Doctor Strange.

The character in Doctor Strange used a staff very similar to the Staff of One and was actually credited as being Tina Minoru. But this character was one of the Masters of the Mystic Arts and trained with the Ancient One (in the prelude comic), so has actual mystical powers.

The actress who played Tina in Doctor Strange, Linda Louise Duan, is a [*cough*] little younger than Brittany Ishibashi, who plays Tina Minoru in Runaways. This could suggest that Runaways is actually set a good few years in the future, but more likely it means that either both Tina's are different or that Runaways isn't actually set in the MCU.

So I can't answer "*when* is Runaways set in the MCU timeline?" because the question of "is Runaways set in the MCU timeline?" hasn't actually been answered anywhere that I am aware of.

Comment: Loeb was clear that it's in the MCU before it started (https://www.thewrap.com/runaways-connect-marvel-cinematic-universe/). Dating is easiest via Cloak and Dagger, since there's an explicit crossover there, after S2 of C&D, during which there's a Luke Cage reference.